# Row count for login concept in springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to create a login concept with spring boot application, so i just need row count of a mysql table, I tried with various internet answers but nothing got solution, please your help and suggestion is appriciate. I will mention my code bellow.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/Login")
public String Login(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    return "login";
}

@PostMapping("/LoginProcess")
public String LoginProcess(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer thecustomer,HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println(thecustomer);
    Customer result = customerservice.Login_service(thecustomer.getUserName(),thecustomer.getPassword());

    if(result==null)
    {
        return "login";
    }
    else if(result.getRole().equals("1"))
    {

        return "admindash";
    }
    else
    {
        //session.setAttribute("jsp_uname", result.getUserName());
        return "customerdash";
    }
}
```

**CustomerImplDao**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.filedemo.model.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements Customerdao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void save(Customer theCustomer) {
        Session cursession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        //If Id=0 then It will do insert or id=x then it will do update
        cursession.save(theCustomer);

    }

    @Override
    public Customer Login(String username,String password) {
        Session cursession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);   
        String hql="from Customer c where c.UserName=:username and c.password=:password";
        Query<Customer> query = cursession.createQuery(hql,Customer.class);
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    Customer theCustomer = query.uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("******************"+query.getResultList().size());
      return theCustomer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: String hql="from Customer c where c.UserName=:username and c.password=:password";

Comment: I need row count for login

Comment: Don't please don't. Your code is flawed in multiple ways and one of them being using plain passwords. Also don't try to role your own mechanism, just use Spring Security and configure the appropriate queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
query.getResultList().size();
```

Or on database siede:

```
entityManager.creteQuery("select count(c) from Customer c where c.UserName=:username and c.password=:password", Long.class).getSingleResult();
```

To do that, you need to inject it on top of your service (bean):

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot from query.getResultList().size(); i am getting the result

Comment: Hi Could you please elaborate the second answer, please (Database side)

Comment: hi i have already added the bean i have updated the question code, Please elaborate the DB answer, becoz no where i found the proper answer for DB side.

Comment: using `EntityManager` allows to count rows within select query. Otherwise you're fetching the list and checking its size.

Comment: ok i will check now if any error comes i will tell you help me please

Comment: Yes but I am eager to know the second one also thats why.

Comment: String hql="select count(c) from Customer c where c.UserName=:username and c.password=:password";
  Query<Customer> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Long.class).getSingleResult();
  query.setParameter("username", username);
  query.setParameter("password", password);
  Customer theCustomer = query.uniqueResult();
  return theCustomer;

Comment: error = Type mismatch: cannot convert from Long to Query<Customer>